# Is there a simple number input with Angular reactive forms and matInput?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

There is no native number validator (https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators), but you can easily do a pattern `Validators.pattern('^[0-9]*$')`.

But even with the validator, the user can still type any character, then get an error or not. How can I have a simple input that will only accept numbers?

**Edit**: my `input="number"` was overwritten by other code that I missed, so my bad, `matInput` does work as a native input when you set it to number.

Comment: In the github issue you linked it clearly states that the matInput uses the type passed and lets the browser handle the behaviour. It also points to examples on the official websites where everything works perfectly. But apparently not on firefox. On the mozilla bug tracker it is well documented: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1398528

Answer (score 1):

Use a directive to enforce input field, which will ensure that only numbers are accepted in the input field.

**Create a OnlyNumberDirective like below and use it in template**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
  selector: '[appOnlyNumber]'
})
export class OnlyNumberDirective {
    constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }
      @HostListener('input', ['$event']) onInputChange(event) {
        const initialValue = this.el.nativeElement.value;
        this.el.nativeElement.value = initialValue.replace(/[^0-9]*/g, '');
        if (initialValue !== this.el.nativeElement.value) {
          event.stopPropagation();
        }
      }
}
```

This directive accept only numeric values in the input field by filtering out any non-numeric characters as the user types.

Answer (score 0):

There is one simple solution for your issue, you can make one method which will do the thing for you like below...

```
numberKeyValidation(event) {
    const charCode = event.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return;
    }
}
```

Then use it on your input fields like this...

```
<input placeholder="Your age..."
       (keypress)="numberKeyValidation($event)"/>
```

This will prevent everything other than numbers.

**TIP:** Make this method in your shared service and use it everywhere.

Happy Coding!!!

Answer (score 0):

To handle validation for input type number, we can create a custom validator that checks for number only. Here's the code snippet:

```js
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
  selector: '[InputFormatter]'
})
export class InputFormatterDirective {
    constructor() { }
      @HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) formatInputText(event) {
      let e = <KeyboardEvent>event;
        if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
      }
}
```

Use it in the HTML(template) of your code like this:

```html
<input type="text" InputFormatter>
```

Hope it helps!!!Happy coding